# Seaborn stripplot deletes plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have a boxplot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
bp = df.boxplot(column='transaction_value', 
           by='store_type', grid=True, 
           ax=ax, showfliers=True)
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.95])
ax.set_ylim([0, 800])
ax.set_ylabel('transaction_value')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have a seaborn stripplot:

```
bplot=sns.stripplot(y='transaction_value', x='store_type', 
                   data=df, 
                   jitter=True, 
                   marker='o', 
                   alpha=0.1,
                   color='black')
```

[image]

When I try to overlay the stripplot on the boxplot, it deletes the first boxplot (on the very far left).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
bp = df.boxplot(column='transaction_value', 
           by='store_type', grid=True, 
           ax=ax, showfliers=True)
bplot=sns.stripplot(y='transaction_value', x='store_type', 
                   data=df, 
                   jitter=True, 
                   marker='o', 
                   alpha=0.1,
                   color='black')
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.95])
ax.set_ylim([0, 500])
ax.set_ylabel('transaction_value')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I stop this from happening?

## Added data example:

```
a
    transaction_value  store_type
0           30.927648     express
1           20.356693       extra
2           48.201950       metro
3           77.213957       metro
4           15.482211  superstore
5           85.794876  superstore
6           16.199844       extra
7            0.007816  superstore
8           50.925737       metro
9           81.393811       metro
10           7.616312  superstore
11          82.172441       metro
12          49.608503       extra
13          71.907878       metro
14          85.833738  superstore
15          88.131029     express
16          11.541427       extra
17          89.759724       metro
18          96.435902  superstore
19          91.984656  superstore
20          67.795293       metro
21          39.806654  superstore
22          39.565823       metro
23          37.507718  superstore
24          37.918300       metro
25          18.599158       metro
26           3.815219       extra
27          83.210068     express
28           3.988503       extra
29          94.298953  superstore

a = pd.read_clipboard()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
bp = a.boxplot(column='transaction_value', 
           by='store_type', grid=True, 
           ax=ax, showfliers=True)
bplot=sns.stripplot(y='transaction_value', x='store_type', 
                   data=a, 
                   jitter=True, 
                   marker='o', 
                   alpha=0.1,
                   color='black')
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.95])
ax.set_ylim([0, 500])
ax.set_ylabel('transaction_value')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It seems `stripplot()` and `boxplot()` can't seem to agree on where to place each categories. It seems `stripplot()` draws at [0-3] and `boxplot()` at [1-4]. It would be helpful to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provide mock-up data. In particular, refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @DizietAsahi Added example using sample data. Cheers

Comment: `df.boxplot(..., positions=np.arange(4))`. And just in case, use the `order` argument in `stripplot` to make sure both plots correlate.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Cheers. You want to add real answer or dupe?

Comment: If you find a duplicate of this (which should exist, but maybe not for the exact combination of boxplot and stripplot?) you can mark as such.

Answer (score 1):

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest provided a solution in comments while I was typing, but I was going to suggest something else:

For better consistency, I would recommend to use seaborn to do the boxplots as well, this should ensure that both plots are laid out the same way,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
sns.boxplot(y='transaction_value', x='store_type', data=df, ax=ax, 
            color='w')
sns.stripplot(y='transaction_value', x='store_type', data=df, ax=ax,
                   jitter=True, 
                   marker='o', 
                   alpha=0.1,
                   color='black')

ax.set_ylabel('transaction_value')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Cheers Diziet, on this occasion I want to keep them Pandas / seaborn separately, but this is viable.